# Just Q & A from Jeopardy JSON

Tags: python, parsing

I downloaded this 200k Q/A of Jeopardy questions. I thought it would be fun to plug into some trivia bot. Anyhow, it's 50M in size with no line breaks that I can see.

I just want to pull all of the questions and answers from this monster into a file format like:

```
-- question
 - answer
```

Here's part of what the file looks like. I know that I can't go line by line and I know I can't load the entire thing into memory. But, I also know that what I want is the first thing in quotes after `"question":` and the answer is the first thing in quotes directly after `"answer":`.

```
[{"category": "HISTORY", "air_date": "2004-12-31", "question": "'For the last 8 years of his life, Galileo was under house arrest for espousing this man's theory'", "value": "$200", "answer": "Copernicus", "round": "Jeopardy!", "show_number": "4680"},
 {"category": "ESPN's TOP 10 ALL-TIME ATHLETES", "air_date": "2004-12-31", "question": "'No. 2: 1912 Olympian; football star at Carlisle Indian School; 6 MLB seasons with the Reds, Giants & Braves'", "value": "$200", "answer": "Jim Thorpe", "round": "Jeopardy!", "show_number": "4680"},
 {"category": "EVERYBODY TALKS ABOUT IT...", "air_date": "2004-12-31", "question": "'The city of Yuma in this state has a record average of 4,055 hours of sunshine each year'", "value": "$200", "answer": "Arizona", "round": "Jeopardy!", "show_number": "4680"}, 
 ...
```

Comment: It's a list of dictionaries, do you have any code you've tried yet?

Comment: Like @JonathanPorter said, it's a list of dictionaries, creating a basic python programme to read the file and sort them into a format that you want shouldn't be too hard although it's hard to see what you're actually asking for.

Comment: Why can't you load a 50M file directly into memory?

Comment: As downshift suggests, 50M isn't that big. If it's valid JSON the Python [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module will easily read it for you.

Comment: I just thought it would take forever, like it was a txt file. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each dictionary in the list, get the `'question'` and `'answer'` keys:

```
for l in d:
    print l['question'], l['answer']
```

output:

```
'For the last 8 years of his life, Galileo was under house arrest for espousing this man's theory' Copernicus
'No. 2: 1912 Olympian; football star at Carlisle Indian School; 6 MLB seasons with the Reds, Giants & Braves' Jim Thorpe
'The city of Yuma in this state has a record average of 4,055 hours of sunshine each year' Arizona
```

Comment: Thanks to all for the help. I didn't know that json files were something awesome. Thanks again!